# JavaScript Memory Leak Issue

Tags: javascript

I am working on a piece of code that has a substancial memory leak, I am posting an example function but my entire 11,000 line code has similar functions repeated all over. I am experiencing an average of 5Mb memory leak when I click the Refresh Button. The logic behind the refresh button is to call the empty function of the object.  I have researched all over for cyclic references and closures but I am not really sure if the way I set everything to an empty array is correct or should I set everything to null ? Any help would be great. I have to use IE as the app is on IE. Sadly no chrome tools for me :(

```js
/**
 * Represents the tasks for the currently loaded patients.
 */
var foo = {
    loaded: false,
    overdueTaskCounts: [],
    unscheduledTaskCounts: [],
    currentTaskCounts: [],
    scheduled: null,
    patientTasks: {},
    tasks: {},
    taskNumber: 0,

    /**
     * Unpacks the JSON received from the CareCompass service for the CareCompass task counts.
     * @param reply - The JSON representing the data returned from the CareCompass service.
     */
    unpack: function unpackTasks(reply) {
        var taskCounts = reply.data; * * //This function populates the variables declared above**//
        this.scheduled = taskCounts.scheduled;
    },
    /**
     * Removes all the task information related to the loaded patients.
     * @param none
     */
    empty: function emptyTasks() {
        this.loaded = false;
        this.overdueTaskCounts = [];
        this.unscheduledTaskCounts = [];
        this.currentTaskCounts = [];
        this.scheduled = null;
        this.patientTasks = {};
    }
}
```

Comment: In JS set an array using `var myArray=new Array();` - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp

Comment: @DavidStarkey A literal is fine.

Comment: Common practice is *not* to use the `Array` constructor, not least because its constructor semantics are inconsistent.

Comment: I would recommend not to use antipattern @DavidStarkey [http://w3fools.com/](http://w3fools.com/) and stick with literals.

Comment: that I what I have been told in school and usually to use literals instead of new Array();

Comment: the main issue is that when I call the empty function would it call garbage collection or not ? if I set everything to an empty array ?

Comment: @user2403006: You were told right.

Comment: They are interchangeable. Even calling Array() directly will result in the same thing as an array literal since the first edition of EcmaScript. Using literals is the standard on most open source projects and the most common code style I've seen in enterprises.

Comment: Stop arguing about how to declare a variable. It's [] and that's it, and it has nothing to do with the question. There isn't enough code to go by to determine if this is even where the memory leak occurs.

Comment: Most of the memories leaks I ever had while programming javascript were due to dynamically creating HTML elements, adding them to the DOM and forgetting to remove them. It's pretty easy to happen when you are adding elements with position:absolute as they will stack on top of each other perfectly.
Also check your libraries, I have had problems with dojo causing memory leaks when updating its charts.

Comment: Quick one: setting `var a = b.c; d.push(a)` (which is what you are doing) causes the entirety of `b` to stay in memory for the scope. Might want to clone the sub-object you are after instead, which would GC `b` the moment you're done with it but keep `c`. Be very wary of circular deps by doing so, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This video from Google I/O will show you how memory leaks happen and how to debug your app. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9Jlu_h_Lyw

Grab some coffee and get ready for a great video.

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned earlier I cannot use Chrome my app is on IE.

Comment: So? You can still debug the memory leak in Chrome.

Comment: I did debug it using this. It really helped.