# JavaScript Memory Leak - Cannot figure out how to clear the variable

Tags: javascript, performance

I [posted a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657150/javascript-memory-leak-issue) that how to debug memory leaks and now I have found the thing that is causing the memory leak in my code.

```
this.hover.click(function() {
        hover.click();
    });

    this.click = function(display, section) {
    if(this.expanded() == true) {
        this.collapse();
        DrillDown.remove(true);
        Table.isSortable = true;
        if(Focus.Focus != null)
            {
                Focus.Focus.ClearFocus();
            }
    }
    else {
        this.expand();
        Table.hideRowHovers(this.person);
        DrillDown.display(this.Row.Cell, this.person, display, section);
        Table.isSortable = true
        if(Focus.Focus != null)
        {
            Focus.personFocus.SetFocus(this.person.Id, this.person.Id2, this.person.name);
        }
    }
}
```

It says that hover.click is holding a reference to the Row object in the line

```
DrillDown.display(this.Row.cell, this.person, display, section);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  

//This is how I am passing the row object
this.hover = new PersonRowHover(this.person);
this.hover.create(this);
this.hover.html = "";
```

Where this.hover.create(this) refers to the PersonRow object that I create for every person. 
I am trying to set it to null but it breaks my code. Any help on how to clear this variable will be grateful. I am trying to clear the this.Row so the Row object gets garbage collected.

Thank You

Comment: May I ask what tool you are using to diagnose the leak?

Comment: What does DrillDown.display do with the cell?

Comment: It is pretty obvious that the reference is needed. `this.Row` won't magically be available if you unset it - JavaScript will keep references for run-time. It's not a bug in this case - you're explicitely telling JS to do so. The solution? Stop cramming into `this` and inject.

Comment: Is it possible to just replace the `this.Row` with the new rows?  Guessing you've got multiple rows you're using here, and the removed rows are not being correctly unset.  Maybe when you remove the row you remove the `this` reference?  This sort of thing is hard to really debug without seeing a lot more code.

Comment: @asawyer see his previous question's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657150/javascript-memory-leak-issue

Comment: I used the HeapMap Profile Google Chrome Dev Tools

Comment: Yes I have multiple Rows and I have to add a hover to each of the Row, so I pass in a reference of the row object, let me add more code to show How I am passing in the Row object

Comment: What is the intended behavior? Do you want `this.Row.Cell` to be a live variable or a fixed value inside the function? I.e., once `this.Row.Cell` is cleared, do you want your function to still know the value or to use `undefined` from then on? In the first case: You could store `this.Row.Cell` in a local variable and then use that one (depending on what type `Cell` has make sure to not just store another reference, but an actual copy). This will allow `this.Row` to be garbage-collected.

Comment: The Cell is a div, this.row.cell changes according to which cell the mouse is being hovered on. so I do not think I would need to retain the prev value, once the mouse is removed all values should be discarded till I hover again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change

```
DrillDown.display(this.Row.cell, this.person, display, section);
```

to

```
var cell = this.Row.cell;
this.Row.cell = null;
DrillDown.display(cell, this.person, display, section);
```

It should allow `this.Row` to be garbage collected if `cell` doesn't have any references to `Row`.